# Odd results from Google Analytics Segments

Tags: google-analytics

I have come across something that I can't explain with some of our Google Analytics segments. I am hoping someone smarter than me can explain this, or confirm that it's just wrong.

When I go to see how many Organic Referrals I have over the past 30 days I get the number 78,293.

[image]

But, when I then apply the segment to kick out certain sessions, the number goes UP to 92,016.

[image]

People are asking for these numbers and I just can't explain them. Can a segment make the numbers rise? Am I going crazy? Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What is your segment based on. Segment filters will affect your end result.

Comment: As Sandeep said...without know your segment settings, this is impossible to answer. The first reaction is to say "yes...this is wrong" ... but if you have a segment filter setup incorrectly, then this could be "correct, but not what you are looking for"

Comment: The segment excludes sessions where browser is not set. I am open to the idea that I screwed up a segment, but I don't understand how viewing a segment would ever 'add' sessions.

Comment: Do you receive any sampling due to your account being too large?

Comment: Yes, it is being sampled. The more I read the more I think the sampled data is just giving me these estimated numbers that are off.

Answer (score 1):

Both the base numbers are same 272,076 - few things to check at

a) See if the dates filters are same for both.
b) See if you did not add any filters on the top eg: Events/Pages/Location/Age /Gender etc

Comment: Dates are the same. No other filters/segments present. The top number is the default 'All Users' segment.